# How to get first index nr/record in child loop

Tags: apex, loop, childrecords, indexing

I have some related records to a parent record. I want to loop trough the child records and set a checkbox on the first record/index to true and all the other records to false.

How do I achieve this? Something similar to:

```
(h.Relatie_Contacten__r).size() for(integer x=0; x<(h.Relatie_Contacten__r).size(); x++) If(x=0) {checkbox=true}else..
```

Loop:

```
for(Huishouden__c h : [SELECT id, (SELECT id, Contactpersoon__r.Birthdate FROM Relatie_Contacten__r WHERE id IN : rcList ORDER BY Contactpersoon__r.Birthdate ASC)FROM Huishouden__c] ) {
        for(Relatie__c rc : h.Relatie_Contacten__c) {

            }  
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a variable to keep track if it's the first record or not:

```
for(Huishouden__c h: [select ... ]) {
  Integer index = 0;
  for(Relatie__c rc: h.Relatie_Contacten__r) {
    rc.First_Record__c = 0 == index++;
  }
}
```

This works because on the first loop, 0 == index will be true, and then the ++ postfix operator will increment index to 1. For each subsequent loop, 0 == index will be false.

Comment: So simple, but effective. Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas You're welcome! Always glad to help.

Answer (score -2):

You could also use the following method

```
for(Huishouden__c h : [SELECT id,...FROM Huishouden__c] ) {

    for(Integer cnt = 0; cnt <= h.Relatie_Contacten__r.size(); cnt++) {

         h.Relatie_Contacten__r.CheckFlag__c = (cnt > 0) ? false : true;
    }  
}
```